# How can I get the X and Y position of a CELL in a table on click?

Tags: javascript

Simple sounding one but cant find the solution :

I have a dynamically generated table (ie so I will never know beforehand how many rows, how high they are, etc etc. ). I have one cell with a button image in it. When I click on the image, I want to get the absolute x and y positions of the top and right values for the button i just clicked.

the reason for this is I have another div that i want to reposition to line up with the row that was just clicked on.

I've already tried creating a click handler for the cell and then using .getAttribute("left") in javascript but that comes back as null.

```html
<td id="test1" onclick="multi(this)">
```

and the following in my js section :

```
function multi(buttonClicked) {

var posY = buttonClicked.getAttribute("top");

alert(posY);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be good with:

```
var posX = buttonClicked.offsetRight;
var posY = buttonClicked.offsetTop;
```

Comment: thanks, it works with a little tweak. i also have to add an offset for the container, since it only returns the y position relative to the top of the table